# Why do I get a routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've got this link:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_profile_path(current_user) %>
```

and it gives me a routing error when I'm trying to access show in the profiles controller.

Here is my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

And here's my show method in the profiles controller:

```
def show
  @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])
end
```

I also have this callback in my User model:

```
before_create :build_profile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should I change it to `@profile = @user.profile.find(params[:id])` then?

Comment: I'm not even sure why you're using `find`. If a user has only one profile, you should be able to do `@profile = @user.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the profile ID.

Something like this:

`<%= link_to "Profile", user_profile_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :id => profile.id) %>`

**edit**

This is pretty filthy, and you should probably not be nesting these objects in the first place, but this will probably get you past your current issue.

`<%= link_to("Profile", user_profile_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :id => current_user.profile.id)) unless current_user.profile.blank? %>`

You should seriously consider un-nesting these in your routes and simply provide access to a profile based on its own ID, and not the ID of the user.

```
resources :users
resources :profiles
```

`<%= link_to("Profile", profile_path(current_user.profile)) unless current_user.profile.blank? %>`

Comment: now I'm getting this error: `RuntimeError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: Undoubtedly you have `nil` for `profile`. You should substitute that for whatever the name of the real object is.

Comment: I did with `@profile`, didn't I? I have no idea why `@profile` is nil

Comment: @Matheus: true. I tend to use a more explicit path helper form, since I've been bitten too many times by objects being out of order. Either way should work.

Comment: @Justin You need to show the controller code that is using the view that contains your profile link. More of that view might also be helpful.

Comment: The controller code is above, although I changed the `show` method to `@profile = @user.profile` after Matheus' comment

Comment: Yeah, I figured. You're pulling this from current_user, so as long as you're checking for that before you try to show a profile link, what I edited into my answer should get you down the right path.

Comment: Could you please explain why nested resources is a bad idea in this case? Also would this require a change in my controller, or no?